# What does a filled black circle mean under PRESENTING SEGUES show relationShip?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I’ve been facing that type of confusion for a long time. In Attribute inspector a `UITableView` controller named `AllListDetailViewController`, Under PRESENTING SEGUES, I have two "show" segues. One is ADD (Action) and the other is All list (Manual). I have two projects with the same code and the problem is that in one file, a black circle is infront of "Add" while in other file it is infront of "All lists". Just help me out as little as u can or just guide me what those circles mean? Any help will be Appreciated.
P.S :- The Add is a barButton and All lists is another `UITableViewController`.

First connections:

[image]

Second connections:

[image]

I expect both of them to be same!

Comment: is not clear what you are aking for, what you mna with a black circle in front

Comment: Here is the link. 1)  https://imgur.com/rV5qBQw 2)  https://imgur.com/AJU4dq7

Comment: Completely unrelated, the next time you want to do screen snapshots in macOS, rather than using your iPhone camera, just press command+shift+4 and it lets you draw a rectangle around that which you want to snapshot and it drops a nice clean image on your macOS desktop. Don’t worry about it here, as we can see what you’re talking about, but just for future reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle with a little dot in it just means “there is one or more ‘show’ segue(s)”. It doesn’t, in this case, mean anything special about “All Lists manual” vs “Add Action”, simply that there are segues present. Don’t worry about to which of your two segues the dot appears, as it always appears in the upper right corner of that bubble. But both segues are hooked up.

So the only question here is why the order of the two segues is different. It is likely some poorly documented internal logic that Xcode employs to determine the order in which they appear.

If you’re really interested, you could look at the source code for your two storyboards (<kbd>control</kbd>-click on the storyboard in the Project Navigator and choose “Open As” » “Source code”), search for “show”, and see if you can divine Xcode’s logic (but would advise against editing the storyboard’s source code as it is frighteningly easy to render it unusable ... if you feel compelled to play around with it, make sure to back up the storyboard file first so you can restore it when you’re done).

Bottom line, the order that the segues appear in the IB user interface (and, thus, which one the dot is closer to) doesn’t matter. Both segues are hooked up.

Comment: Thanks Alot sir. Really appreciate your reply. And yeah I got that.